# how to display device address book ordered by custom external data

Tags: android, android-contacts

In my android application I would like to display the mobile user's contacts (names, profile picture ) displaying first the contacts that have already installed and registrered that application (the matching is made by contact's email).

Trying to loop over each contact and match if their email is already registered (in an external SQLITE table) don't seems to be an efficient way.

I would like to directly add (somewhere in the address book ?) the extra data "isRegistered = true/false) and order my addreess book query by this value to scroll the address book.
Is it possible? How to implement this in detail ?

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION 1**

I think the most efficient way would be what you thought about initially, with a slight improvement:

1. store the list of registered emails (for the user's contacts) in a local `SQLite` DB.
2. read the **entire list of emails** on application launch, and store them in a `HashSet`
3. When sorting the contacts, create a custom Comparator to first check if the contact is an app user or not, and only then fallback to name compare.

**OPTION 2**

If you still want to check the option of storing the custom value in the Contacts DB, and integrate it into your query, you need to create a `SyncAdapter`.

This is basically a service that is able to sync contacts to/from a server into your own RawContact, which is then aggregated into one-or-more existing RawContacts, like `Google` does for `Google Contacts`. 
You can set it to be notified when a new contact is added, and have your `SyncAdapter` add the needed info to the contact so it'll show links to your app.

If you go to your phone settings > accounts, you can see `Whatsapp` and Google's `SyncAdapters` there, where you can turn them off/on.

To create a sync adapter, you can follow the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html), or this [great tutorial](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/).

Comment: Thanks. For option 1 it might use too much memory if the address book is big isn't it ? For option too as e "newby" in android it might be difficult to master and complete the "whatsapp" way (wich is actually what I need); and once this SyncAdapter will be completed I'm still confuse to know if the address book query will have good performance and if it will be possible to query the native address book with this nex raw data

Comment: you can hold thousands of emails in memory without a problem, if you're worried, you can only hold the hash value of each email instead of the email itself, this will reduce the memory needed significantly and would still allow you to compare emails by comparing hash values.

Comment: also, I think the performance of option 1 would be better then option 2

Comment: how about storing as you say email in hashset (or the corresponding contact's lookup key) and query the address book with a kind of query like "select ...where lookup key IN  {my huge list of lookup key registered"). Is it possible to query address book like this ?  Because all exemple I found that scrool address book are using directly the cursor not a list to order)

Comment: do you want to **sort** the entire contact list to registered contacts would be on top, or do you want to **filter** the contacts list to it'll show only registered contacts? those are two different things

Comment: I want to be able to scroll the entire addrress book, but displaying first the already registered  contacts, then the other scontacts. Generally android application use the Cursor to scroll this list but it more complex with this external criterium

Comment: i think you have no choice but read all contacts to a list, and display the list in the activity. Even if you create a SyncAdapter and store the value in the DB itself, you can't use it for sorting as the contacts data is saved across 3 different tables: `contacts`, `raw-contacts`, and `data`. The value you'll be adding would be in `data` which can't be a sort for the contacts table.